# Is it possible to force images to be a set height but still remain responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm using a movie API to get some image posters and display them in a grid, the problem is that about 10% of all the posters aren't the same size as the rest, thus causing the grid system to be littered with whitespace and causing other images to jump down.

Here you can see what I mean:

[image: example image of problem]

The poster marked in red in the upper right corner causes the poster with Bruce Willis to take up space in the upper "row" which then breaks the float flow altogether.

The jumping down can be fixed by having inline-block and no float on the grid elements but that causes whitespace over and below the images which just looks horrible.

Here's how that looks:

[image: example image nr 2]

Here's my markup for this:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1 class="text-center">Similar movies</h1>
  <div ng-repeat="movie in similarMovies" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 cut-off">
    <a href="#/movies/{{movie.id}}">
      <figure>
        <img ng-src="{{getSrc(movie.poster_path)}}" alt="{{movie.title}}" class="image enlarge">
      </figure>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap's grid system for this.

Now my question is, can I somehow make the posters 100% of the `div` height that it sits in, causing all posters to be equal height but still scale property when resizing the screen?

I presume that the only way to achieve this is via some hacky JavaScript solution?

Comment: Personally, I would do this the other way around. I would set a height and/or max-height for each and every image, and thus the height of the <div>s would be determined by their content. It also means that if some images are low resolution, they would still be rendered the same height as all the others.

Comment: @KieranPotts Problem is that they come from an API, and if I have to run some sort of mapping function for every image it feels like it would slow things down a lot.

Comment: The question is difficult to understand, does this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1pvohjho/) help?

Comment: @Pangloss I think it's quite clear, I tried using table cells but it doesn't work well when you have to use ng-repeat in angular to loop out the elements, then I have to insert a table row for every 2-4 elements depending on screen size and it just became a mess very very quickly.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz not sure what exactly it's supposed to look like, so can the table layout fix the height problem? and it sounds like a simple loop if you have a fixed number of images in each row, you can also use table row for that, but I don't know much about angular.

Comment: @Pangloss Just imagine a grid of 20+ (I will add a lazy load function in the future to load more when user scrolls down). I'm gonna have to try Masonry and salvattore as suggested by the answer below before I can investigate how I would accomplish it with css table rules I think.

Answer (score 0):

If your inline-block/no float solution is close, but it's just the space above and below the images that's an issue, there might be some easy fixes. Without seeing the actual final output and a working page example, I'll take a stab at that particular issue.

Ensure you style your 'figure' element first, set margins to 0em to override most browser defaults, which will insert 1em top/bottom margins and usually some on the sides.

Ensure your img element for your posters is styled with a line-height of 0em and maybe a text-align:bottom (or top as you prefer).

You might also style both elements with overflow:hidden!important.

Otherwise, you can approach the height issue a few ways. There is always min-height:100% that you can use on the images if you've set a default height for the parent containing element. Or set a min-height in pixels or ems for the images themselves, and order a few properties.

max-height:100%
height:auto
min-height:300px

If you have a set height for the figure or div element, you could always approach the markup differently, and instead of using the figure element, substitute something else with the poster images as background images, using the background-size:cover approach (consider you would probably want images not to differ too greatly in size, say no more than 15-25% height difference), if you have some content to insert in the container (a link).

Or, background-size:100%; background-repeat:no-repeat would yield somewhat the same results.

Another option is that you might for your image elements in this use case, whip up a custom, and very tiny, responsive grid just for them--instead of using Bootstrap's. Or, try running a script that works on the images pulled from the API, resizing on the fly. You might even assign images a class with uniform height and width first, and then inline a style, and use the style to set responsive functionality, as it will override the class already set. Set dimensions uniformly, then override, you may or may not have luck with that. We don't like inline styles, I know...but sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.

Assuming a responsive parent container of x% and different sized images:

Class on img tag to uniform size...
height:400px!important;
width:250px!important;

Followed by inline style...
width:100%!important;

No javascript needed.

In any event, you're looking at a lot of browser overhead if you're not uniforming the images server-side.